# Restart Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

Quite me to this stuff, but I seem to miss something. I push an image to a private Azure registry and spawned a container instance right through the portal. Works like a charm. Now I changed something, pushed again and...  What do I do? Kill and delete the instance and recreate? Everytime?
Br,
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

Another good way to do this these days is to restart the container. You can run the Azure CLI command or do it from the front end.

`az container restart -g="XXX" -n="XXX"`

An added benefit is that your public IP stays the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-restart

Comment: No you would have to do a build and a push first

Comment: you need to do az container create to the upgrade. However, this is useful because I have seen ACI not showing the new changes. Restarting it (with this command) helps for this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to delete every time! **Just make sure your docker tag is always the same** then after pushing you can just restart your app service.

tag example

`docker tag myimage image.azure.ac/myimage:latest`

latest in this case it's my tag

Answer (score 1):

Generally - yes. But you can create a webhook that will invoke something when a new image is pushed to the repo. That can act as a way to automate redeployment.

[image]

possible solution is to use Azure Managed DNS name for container:

```
az container create -n helloworld --image microsoft/aci-helloworld -g myResourceGroup --dns-name-label mycontainer
```

this way your dns name will always stay the same

Comment: That's dumb. I'll lose the public IP everytime then.

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't mind to kill, remove, create again, if I wouldn't lose the public IP then.

Comment: Will look into that asap.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the container using the portal like the following:
[image]

Or use the following Azure CLI command if the container is on a `running` state.

```
az container restart --name <container_instance_name> --resource-group <RG_name>
```

To confirm the successful pull/update of the image, you should see a `pull` event before the `start` event near the time you restarted, like the following:
[image]

Comment: Hello @Wail, this requieres that the container was created with tag `latest`, doesn't it?

Comment: @KenJiiii my apologies for the late reply, it can be `latest` or any other `tag` that's getting updated, depending on your tagging strategy of course. If you are relying only on build, version or commit tags for example, this won't work for you.